# htaccess problem

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a few lines in my .htacess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.org [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/
RewriteRule index.php/(.*) http://forum.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code is works well, but i dont know if the code is standard.

I would like to set htaccess to:

```
* mydomain.org go to www.mydomain.org (its ok..)
* mydomain.org/index.php go to www.mydomain.org (its ok..)
* forum.mydomain.org stay forum.mydomain.org (its ok..? )
* www.forum.mydomain.org go to forum.mydomain.org (how?)
```

Could anyone help me to fix this code?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question, whether the rules are set all right or do you need to change the rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the `* www.forum.mydomain.org go to forum.mydomain.org (how?)`, you need to add this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forum.mydomain.org [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.mydomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is to configure a htaccess doc in your root public_html directory and subdomain directory. The root instructs the browser to use www and the subdomain doesn't.

Why do you want to show spammers where your blog is located? Its like hanging this sign on your home: front door is open.

Comment: .htaccess files are a hack. Simple, maybe, but not correct.

Comment: nonsense, htaccess are directives to apache before the site is hit. If you're referring to server configuration then I agree but from a client configuration, many directives are required because server admins are lazy.